# Is it impossible to fund EOS Testnet ADDRESS + MEMO?

Tags: testnet

**How can I fund this EOS Testnet account?**

- address: qi1lzjkyntve
- memo: 2ewUBwtRY

Jungle3, Scatter, testnet.eos.io, testnet.help/en/eosfaucet/testnet (& others) are NOT working!

Those EOS Testnets only allow users to create a NEW account/key, and then directly fund them there.

**Is it impossible to fund an address/memo pair that was generated by a crypto exchange?**

Answer (score 1):

I successfully used the Jungel3 faucet at https://monitor3.jungletestnet.io/#faucet to send tokens to qi1lzjkyntve

Seems to work fine.

Scatter is not a testnet.

Comment: Thanks Matthew! Really appreciate it.
Is it possible to send funds to a MEMO using Jungle3?

Comment: Sure, just it works just like any other EOSIO chain.  For example you can use jungle3.bloks.io See help here: https://docs.bloks.io/wallet/transfer

Comment: You can't transfer Jungle tokens to any exchanges though, since no exchanges will accept it.